# nginx $server_name is always localhost

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, localhost, server-name

I have an nginx 1.4.5 server running on an AWS EC2 instance. I have two conf file: the `default.conf` and `myapp.conf`. The `default.conf` listen to localhost, and `myapp.conf` listen to `myapp.mydomain.com`.

However I found even I type in `myapp.mydomain.com` in the browser, it always load the `default.conf`. I've changed the `log_format` in `nginx.conf` file add a `"$server_name"` field to check the server name of each request. I found it's always `localhost`.

Any one has any idea about this?

**Updates with configuration info**

the `nginx.conf`

```
server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  localhost;

     #charset koi8-r;
     #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

     location / {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         index  index.html index.htm;
     }
...
}
```

The `myapp.conf`

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name myapp.mydomain.com;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.log;

     location / {
         add_header P3P 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"';
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/;
         set $ssl off;
         if ($scheme = https) {
             set $ssl on;
         }
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $ssl;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     }
 }
```

And yes I am behind two firewalls, one is iptable, the other one is AWS built in secure group

Comment: Can you post the config please, also - confirm that it isn't behind a proxy?

Comment: The only thing i could think of is maybe you're trying to access a `www` site when you only defined one without in the nginx conf, is that the case?, try appending the `www` alternative in the server name if it's applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Someone with a [similar problem](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-setup-separate-config-files-for-different-sites-on-nginx) got it fixed by:

> I've fixed this now, in case anyone has the same problem as me it was
>   to do with "`server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`" in
>   `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.`
>
> That line was commented out by default so I uncommented and restarted
>   nginx and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are running the browser and nginx on the same machine. In that case `myapp.mydomain.com` probably resolves to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` thus nginx thinks it's going to localhost.

Try adding this to your /etc/hosts file:

```
<external IP of your host>  myapp.mydomain.com
```

You should also try accessing your nginx server from another machine.

Comment: No nginx is running on AWS ec2 instance. Browser is on my laptop

Comment: Then why the heck do you need localhost ?

Comment: You are not running the default on localhost. If you were, it would have `listen 127.0.0.1:80;`. I assume that the missing semicolon on the server_name is lost in copying, but you should check for any typos.

Comment: That's my typo on SO (and fixed now). Not the typo in nginx conf file, otherwise nginx wouldn't get started.